# How does several multithreaded processes behave in a multicore CPU?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Note: I'm unsure about this topic so I apologise before hand !

Lets say you have the following processes waiting in RAM:

P1= Spotify and P2 = Microsoft Word

These are 2 multithreaded processes aka user-level threads.

Further, assume I have multicore CPU (Quad core with 4 cores) which based on asymmetric multiprocessing.

What I don't understand when it comes to Operating Systems, especially multiple multithreaded processes, is how can I listen to Spotify music in the background while editing a file in Microsoft Word ?

Are these processes executed one by one utilising all cores on the Quad core; but everything is happening so fast that it forms this illusion that these processes are occurring simultaneously (parallelism) ? Moreover, are the threads of 1 multithreaded processes utilising all cores and the other multithreaded processes are waiting in the ready queue in RAM ?

Or, are these processes actually in the running state at the same time (parallelism) ?

For instance, you have Spotify who is utilising two cores but in the GUI it's running in the background while the music is playing, and I have Microsoft Word open and its running in the foreground where its GUI is displayed utilising the other two cores.

I have tried to read about this on several different blogs but I still don't feel like I got a good answer.

Comment: In your example, neither process is using a large amount of CPU.  Threads in Spotify will run briefly when network data arrives or audio buffers need reloading.  Word will use next-to-no CPU while handling keypresses.  Both processes are mostly blocked on I/O, only occasionally having threads assigned to cores as I/O completion interrupts make tbreads ready and request a scheduling run.

Comment: If you were listening to a music video on YouTube instead of listening to Spotify, you would see more CPU use in your Task Manager, but still, YouTube+Word would not trouble even one core:)

Comment: Thank you, Martin, for your response. So these two processes would be considered  I/O bound correct ? If we disregard the aforementioned processes and solely consider CPU bound multithreaded processes, in a quad core CPU, how many processes can run at one instance ?

Comment: Four threads can be running, possibly from four different processes.